# SELECT Record that have start date and enddate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
id startDate  Enddate
1  01-01-2020  NULL
1  02-01-2020  NULL
1  03-01-2020  NULL
1  04-01-2020  NULL
1  05-01-2020  05-01-2020
1  08-01-2020  NULL
1  09-01-2020  NULL
1  10-01-2020  NULL
1  11-01-2020  11-10-2020
```

And we want the output

```
id startdate     Enddate
1  01-01-2020    05-01-2020
1  08-01-2020    11-10-2020
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT t.ID, MIN(t.startdate) AS StartDate, MAX(t.Enddate) AS EndDate
FROM table t OUTER APPLY
     ( SELECT TOP (1) t1.Enddate
       FROM table t1
       WHERE t1.id = t.id AND t1.startdate >= t.startdate AND t1.enddate IS NOT NULL
       ORDER BY t1.startdate  
     ) t1
GROUP BY t.ID, t1.Enddate;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select * from YourTable where (startDate is not null and  Enddate is not null)
```

Comment: How does this differ from the existing answer?

Comment: they are the same just we posted in the same time!

Comment: You didn't post at the same time - look at the time stamps on the answers - you were 2 whole minutes later.

Comment: when I posted the answer there was not any answer on your question.2 minutes is not a big difference anyway

Comment: Sure, but there is no point leaving an exact duplicate answer - it happens to all of us, just delete it.

Comment: Either way it doesn't give the OP's expected output

Comment: ID STARTDATE ENDDATE
1 2020-05-01 2020-05-01
1 2020-11-01 2020-11-10 NOT Desirable o/p

Comment: @UMESHKUMAR Commenting on answer in case does not get the required is good but as an OP your first priority should be give the details scenario with the logic for the output. You have given heading, sample data and expected output but do not specified the logic of expected output. Thanks.